# CIL instruction "isinst [System.Runtime]System.Int32" for value 0 (int32) - what will return?

Tags: c#, cil, mono.cecil

I have a simple C# function

```
public bool Isinst_intSimple(object value)
{
    return value is int;
}
```

As expected `Isinst_intSimple(0)` returns `true`

After decompiling, the function looks like:

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldarg.1      // 'value'
IL_0002: isinst       [System.Runtime]System.Int32
IL_0007: ldnull
IL_0008: cgt.un
IL_000a: stloc.0      // V_0
IL_000b: br.s         IL_000d

// [196 9 - 196 10]
IL_000d: ldloc.0      // V_0
IL_000e: ret
```

**What will the `IL_0002 isinst [System.Runtime]System.Int32` instruction push on the evaluation stack after execution (the input will be 0(int32))?**

According to the MS documentation, the `Isinst` instruction should return an object reference - [The result (either an object reference or a null reference) is pushed onto the stack.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.isinst?view=net-5.0)

But what is the reference to 0? and if. What should the instruction `IL_0008: cgt.un` do?

### My interpretation

In my interpretation of all the IL instruction - the function retrun `0`. And I can't find a way to return `true`.

Below is my interpretation of the function execution:

```
 IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldarg.1      // push 0 on evaluation stack – stack after {0}
IL_0002: isinst       [System.Runtime]System.Int32    //pop and object reference is pushed onto the stack. - stack after { 0* or reference to 0 – boxing? }
IL_0007: ldnull //– stack after {null, 0*}
IL_0008: cgt.un //– 0* is not greater than null so its return 0 -  stack after {0}
IL_000a: stloc.0      // V_0 – pop to V_0 – stack after {}
IL_000b: br.s         IL_000d // – stack after {}

// [196 9 - 196 10]
IL_000d: ldloc.0      // V_0 //– push V_0 – stack after {0}
IL_000e: ret    //return {0}
```

I think the problem is in `IL_0002: isinst` or `IL_0008: cgt.un`, but I can't find it.

### Background

I'm working on a Virtual Machine that emulates C# dll - instruction by instruction (executing C# in "virtual machine") but I have problem simulating a test function `Isinst_intSimple(0)`. My version return `0` but it should return `true`

Comment: [isinst](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.isinst): "Tests if an object reference is an instance of class, *returning either a null reference or an instance of that class or interface.*" The boolean state is whether or not that result is `null`, so `cgt.un` is comparing that result to the null loaded with `ldnull` and that gives you 1 or 0 (effectively, the boolean value).

Comment: The local usage you are seeing only exists because you obtained the IL code of a debug build. Compiled as release the code is even simpler: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgRg9nCACAkgZzAOzcA+l4AZTAFsAHCAUwAo4YArSgY2CQDcBDCAV0oEoAsACgA3sKQSkAAQDs7LryRg0SzMADcwgL5A

Comment: @madreflection -  `cgt.un` - Compares two values.If the first value is greater than the second, the integer value 1. - Not null is greater than null? hmmm.. sounds like the answer - I will check the tests

Comment: Yes. If the value you tested was a reference to a boxed int, it gives you that reference. `cgt.un` does an unsigned comparison of that (non-null) reference to zero (null from `ldnull`). Anything that's not null will be greater than zero.

Comment: @madreflection - this is a good answer - not null is greater than null :) - the problem was in my interpretation `cgt.un` - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[ECMA-335 specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_6th_edition_june_2012.pdf), which defines IL bytecode, says the following:**

> **I.12.1.6.2.6 `castclass` and `isinst` on value types**
>
> Casting to and from value type instances isn’t permitted (the equivalent operations arebox and unbox). When boxed, however, it is possible to use the `isinst` instruction to see whether a value of type `System.Object` is the boxed representation of a particular class.

> **III.4.6 - `isinst`**
>
> Test if `obj` is an instance of `typeTok`, returning `null` or an instance of that class or interface.
>
> **Stack Transition**:  ..., obj => ..., result
>
> **Description**: `typeTok` is a metadata token (a typeref, typedef or typespec), indicating the desired class. If `typeTok` is a non-nullable value type or a generic parameter type it is interpreted as “boxed” `typeTok`
>
> **Verifiability**: Verification tracks the type of `result` as `typeTok`.

So the result of `isinst` on a value-type (struct) is a boxed ObjectRef to the value.

> **II.1.5 Operand type table**
>
> `cgt.un` is allowed and verifiable on ObjectRefs (O). This is commonly used when comparing an ObjectRef with null (there is no “compare-not-equal” instruction, which would otherwise be a more obvious solution)

**So `isinst` `ldnull` `cgt.un` will tell you if an object is of a particular type**